# How to change the colour of li tag on hover effect in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get an orange hover effect when I hover over each link in bootstrap. I don't want the link text colour to change but I want there to be a background-color:orange; for each li tag itself.

does anyone know how can I replicate that hover effect with this html code:

```css
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li:hover {

 background:orange;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Server Plex</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#example">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here" />
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your code works just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best advice i can give you for changing bootstrap classes, especially bootstrap classes that are nested inside other bootstrap classes such as `navbar`. Create an `ID` and select from the ID and then use the `>` operator to go through the DOM...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="main-navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Server Plex</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#example">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here" />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>
```

```
#main-navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li:hover {

  background:orange;
}
```